# Wildcard properties in Swagger?

Tags: swagger

I have a JSON response which may have any number of nodes, and the names may vary too. For example:

```
{
  thing: "this a thing"
  other: "this is another thing"
  another: "and yet another thing"
}
```

Is there a way to indicate it in Swagger that the object may contain any number of properties, each with any name?

```
type: object
properties:
  *:
    type: string
    repeats: infinitely
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The `additionalProperties` flag means exactly that an unknown number of optional fields are to follow. They can have types like regular `properties`.

```
type: object
additionalProperties:
  type: string
```

Thank you.